# delete data from mongodb collection when date was get expired

Tags: node.js, mongodb, triggers

I had a collection which holds user session and it has a field expiry date. I am looking for a trigger like function in MongoDB which triggered when any of the records dates get expired and I can delete that record.

here is how my collection look like

```
{
 _id:"123",
 sessionId:"dummy",
 token:"asdasd",
 deviceId:"123213",
 expiryDate:"date"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `expiryDate` is an actual `Date` type and not a string, you can use a [TTL index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-ttl/) to do this.

```
db.mycoll.createIndex({expiryDate: 1}, {expireAfterseconds: 0})
```

Will instruct MongoDB to automatically delete documents from the collection once the current time is greater than `expiryDate`.

Comment: thanks it works .but what if I want to move that record to some other collection.?

Comment: @AshishPatel That's a very different question; you would have to do that yourself.